# Is there a CMS system can be used with HTML

Tags: html, web, content-management-system

I am working on a portfolio website for a client where they need to be able to upload their work: videos and photos, and some text with (title, short description). Normally I would make such a website with a system like Wordpress, however, the way the website would work is not possible to build with Wordpress (unusual navigation and a more dynamic/animated way to switch between pages). So, I want to build this website by HTML and then connect a CMS system where they can upload their work, which will then properly loaded into HTML pages. I have tried to google solutions, but I cannot find a good approach/tool to do this. Does anyone have a good recommendation for me? Thank in advance, Jip Asveld

Answer (score 0):

I think Wordpress theme is the best solution.
It is very easy to create Wordpress theme from HTML.
Of course, you can CMS functionality to the theme.
You can refer various documents by Google.
For instance, this is one of the documents.
https://websitesetup.org/html-to-wordpress/

Comment: Interesting, I will look into this approach. So it does not matter that my website does not have the regular wordpress-like site structure and way of navigating pages?

Comment: Yes, almost websites can be converted into Wordpress type.

Answer (score 0):

Have you concisered a headless cms like https://forestry.io/? This ideal for static html websites, which you could combine with a framework like https://gohugo.io/ to build such a site.

Comment: Forestry looks very promising! Unfortunately, it does not seem to support videos (yet? https://portal.productboard.com/forestry/1-forestry-io/tabs/1-under-consideration) which are an important part of my client's portfolio. Thanks for the suggestion though, I will definitely explore Forestry!